# CloudFormation: How to use Fn::Import value in conditions?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have two stacks, the VPC deployment stack and my app deployment stack. In VPC stack, I am exporting value called as EnvType which can be a dev, prod or staging. As per this exported value, I want to deploy one resource in app deployment stack. If EnvType = dev, then don't deploy it. Otherwise, deploy it. 
How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this, as `ImportValue` **can't be used in conditions**.

You can easily verify that using the two sample templates:

**bucket1.yaml** (exports `EnvType`)

```
---
Resources:

  MyBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

Outputs:

  EnvType:
    Value: "prod"
    Export:
      Name: EnvType
```

**bucket2.yaml** (imports `EnvType` and tries to use it in `IsProd` condition)

```
---
Conditions:

  IsProd:
    !Equals [!ImportValue EnvType, 'prod']

Resources:

  MyBucket2:
    Condition: IsProd
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
```

Comment: Ugh still the case in Dec 2022. AWS console stack creation fails with "Template error: Cannot use Fn::ImportValue in Conditions."